# Favorites not refreshing upon post to database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

What changes do you suggest that I should implement in order to resolve the issue of the Favorites not refreshing upon post to database?  The user can click a heart to favorite a recipe.  The heart is supposed to turn from white to red once the user clicks it, thus adding the recipe to their favorites list.  What is happening is that the heart doesn't change colors & the favorited recipe doesn't appear in the favorites list until the user refreshes the screen.  This app has been coded in React, and here are the two files that I believe would be controlling this:

Recipe:

```
const Recipe = ({ recipe }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const { label, image, url, ingredients } = recipe.recipe;
  const favorites = useContext(FavoritesContext);
  const recipeIsInMyFavorites =
    favorites.findIndex(
      (favorite) => favorite.recipe.uri === recipe.recipe.uri
    ) > -1;
  const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const addToFavorites = () => {
    instance.post(`users/${uid}/favorites.json`, recipe).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      alert("This recipe has been added to your favorites' list");
    });
  };
  const noop = () => {
    alert("This recipe is already a favorite");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="recipe">
        <h2>
          {label}
          <Popup
            trigger={
              <i
                className="fa fa-heart"
                style={{
                  fontSize: "30px",
                  color: recipeIsInMyFavorites ? "red" : "white",
                  float: "right",
                }}
                onClick={() =>
                  recipeIsInMyFavorites ? noop() : addToFavorites()
                }
              />
            }
            content="Click to favorite recipe"
            position="top left"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#FAD5DF",
              color: "black",
              fontSize: "20px",
            }}
          />
        </h2>
```

FavoritesContext:

```
export const FavoritesContext = createContext();

export function FavoritesProvider(props) {
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);
  const { children } = props;

  // Make the DB Call
  useEffect(() => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      db.ref(`users/${uid}/favorites`).on("value", (snapshot) => {
        console.log("favorites: ", snapshot.toJSON());

        const results = Object.entries(snapshot.toJSON() || {}).map(
          ([id, props]) => ({
            id,
            ...props,
          })
        );
        setFavorites(results);
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <FavoritesContext.Provider value={favorites}>
      {children}
    </FavoritesContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: You probably need a `useEffect` hook in the Recipe component. This way you know when you have new data coming back from your save.

Comment: that sounds good, but how would i implement it?

Comment: from what i've seen on youtube, useEffect is useful whenever posting to an api, but i'm just not seeing anything about posting to a database

Answer (score 1):

this is what needed to be changed in my code:

```
const [recipeIsInMyFavorites, setRecipeIsInMyFavorites] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setRecipeIsInMyFavorites(
      favorites.some((favorite) => favorite.recipe.uri === recipe.recipe.uri)
    );
  }, [favorites, recipe.recipe.uri]);
```